# CSV file placed in public folder of ROR, its content gets erased daily automatically. (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github

I have a CSV file placed in the public folder of my Herkou App. But the content of this file gets erased daily. What can be the issue and how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: first of all check is there any cronjob.

Comment: How can i check that? I haven't added any crob job.

Comment: try this: `crontab -l` on heroku

Comment: How did you place that file there? Is it part your code base (in the repository) or did you upload or create that file later on? Files that are not part of the repository might disapear (read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: It is uploaded from the app frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most PaaS providers, Heroku [does not provide a persistent filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

In other words, anything you upload through the web will be lost whenever you deploy a new version or when your dyno gets restarted. [Dynos get restarted frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (emphasis mine):

> The dyno manager restarts all your app’s dynos whenever you:
>
> - create a new release by deploying new code
> - change your config vars
> - change your add-ons
> - run `heroku restart`
>
> *Dynos are also restarted at least once per day*, in addition to being restarted as needed for the overall health of the system and your app.

The recommended way to store user uploads on Heroku is to [use something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3):

> AWS S3, or similar storage services, are important when architecting applications for scale and are a perfect complement to Heroku’s ephemeral filesystem.

Comment: This could not have been explained in a clearer manner. Even though Heroku has taken the time explicitly state this. I see this question frequently so hopefully this will help many users that stumble across this answer.